# How to select multiple pod for a service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I want to link services to specific pod by using `StatefulSets` in Kubernetes as below.

- `service_1` links to `web-0`, `web-1` pod
- `service_2` links to `web-2`, `web-3` pod

I know there is a label to select specific pod

"statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: web-01"

but this label seems only select one pod. Is there a way to select multiple pod?

Comment: What is your use case? Why?

Comment: currently, a service is configured in that way with internal load balancer and instances in aws and we want to migrate this service to k8s cluster with same architecture but it seems k8s doesn't support this feature to implement.

Comment: Did you try giving two pod names like this "statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: web-01, web-02" ?

Comment: Yes , I did. but it didn't' work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to point services into a portion of pods in a StatefulSet, the best practice is to create multiple StatefulSets, or use [Canary Deployments with StatefulSets](https://cloud.redhat.com/blog/simple-canary-deployments-using-kubernetes-statefulsets-on-openshift)

If you need to know **how to point a service into a StatefulSet**, there is three options:

1. [Create a headless service for the StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#creating-a-statefulset).
2. Use the service name as the hostname in the StatefulSet pod specification.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: my-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: my-statefulset
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-statefulset
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-statefulset
    spec:
      hostname: my-statefulset
      subdomain: my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
      containers:
      - name: my-container
        image: my-image
        command: ["/bin/sh"]
        args: ["-c", "while true; do sleep 3600; done"]
```

3. Use environment variables or DNS resolution to connect to the service from within the pod.

---

To point a service to multiple pod names, there is no possible way,
According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/#label-selectors):

> Caution: For both equality-based and set-based conditions there is no
> logical OR (||) operator. Ensure your filter statements are structured
> accordingly

Comment: I don'k know why my comment is deleted,. so my understanding for first and second options are to create two statefulset and two service objects and each service points to each statefulset, am I right?

Comment: @user2286858 Its technically possible and valid. but still depends of state management mechanisms of your service.

Comment: got it! Aref Riant. thanks so much for answering!! :-)